# java robot ввод данных

Tags: java

Как разбить переменную `String` на символы так, чтобы можно было ввести их в текстовое поле посредством класса `Robot()`? Просто, чтобы ввести данные, их нужно добавлять в код по одной букве, и в таком виде, насколько я понял:

```
    r.keyPress('K');
    r.keyRelease('K');
    r.keyPress('E');
    r.keyRelease('E');
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    r.keyPress('Y');
    r.keyRelease('Y');
```

При этом вводятся строчные буквы, хотя в коде они заглавные. 
Проблема заключается в том, что мне хотелось бы вводить строку в `JTextArea`, и чтобы Robot ее вводил многократно.

Как заставить этот класс распознавать строки и вводить их?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы тебе вводить строку целиком, необходимо cоздать ассоциацию буквы из строки ( `char`) с соответствующим полем класса `java.awt.KeyEvent`. ( ну на самом деле там просто интовые значения, но все равно удобно).

Например, `'a'` - это `KeyEvent.VK_A`. `'b'` - `KeyEvent.VK_B`.

Код будет таким :

```
robot.pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.releaseKey(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Если необходимо ввести большую букву, необходимо сначала зажать `shift`, ввести маленькую букву, и отжать `shift`. Соответственно, код будет следующим:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
roboy.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Правильно ли я понял? Для того, чтобы можно было вводить произвольный текст в JTextArea, нужно связать каждую букву алфавита с данным кодом?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Потому что robot.pressKey('a') это не то же самое, что robot.pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_A)

Comment: Еще раз большое Вам спасибо.) Так и сделаю.

Comment: А если не секрет - зачем тебе ввод данных через робота? Может быть тебе надо что-то автоматизировать в свинговом приложении? Тогда тебе поможет библиотека fest https://code.google.com/archive/p/fest

Comment: Робот мне нужен для автоматического тестирования сайтов по заданному сценарию.

Comment: Если тестирование сайтов, которые в вебе, посмотрите в сторону библиотеки selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Вот сейчас посмотрел про selenium. Это получается, что она идет как замена браузера?

Comment: Не совсем. Используется специальный драйвер, который общается с браузером. Ты говоришь драйверу что сделатЬ, а он уже выполняет это в браузере

Comment: Похоже на то, что это решение будет лучше робота. Огромнейшее Вам спасибо) Я действительно теперь понял, как это все сделать гораздо проще чем предполагалось)