# Java - эмуляция ввода

Tags: java

Можно ли в Java юзать эмуляцию клавиатуры, и как это сделать ? С помощью Robot я разобрался только как вводить единичные символы - т.е. по одному. Пытаясь сделать это в цикле - как-то так:

```
for(char ch:str.toCharArray()){
    robot.keyPress((int)ch);
    robot.keyRelease((int)ch);
}
```

выходит какая-то ересь. Есть ли какой-нибудь метод, типа `someMethod("text")`, которой отправляет в текстбокс переданную ему аргументом строку ? Если кто-то подскажет java api для Sikuli - тоже буду рад ответу.

Comment: см http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489399/java-robot-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: здесь рекомендуют просто эмулировать Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665534/type-a-string-using-java-awt-robot (код в выбранном ответе)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал так, оказывается, все просто: после того, как курсор оказался в поле для ввода, нужно просто вызвать метод type для объекта Screen и передать ему аргументом нужную строку. И все работает. [sikuli api for java]

UPD_0:

```
public class GITest {
    private Screen _screen;
    .......
    private static final String _user = "user_139";
    .......
}
private void setPersonalData(){
    try{
        // сейчас курсор окажется в текстбоксе
        _screen.click("img/004.png");
        // следующая операция - ввод
        _screen.type(_user);
        ........
    } catch (FindFailed | InterruptedException ex){
        _rbuffer.append("One of searching element not find.\n");
        writeLogBufferToFile();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно пример кода? Очень поможете сообществу

Comment: Сейчас как update добавлю

Comment: Лучше отредактируйте это сообщение и потом выберите его как правильный ответ:)